# Cron does not execute my Python script

Tags: cron, python

I'm trying without success to execute a Python script using cron on a
Debian Jessie Raspberry Pi.

I can execute the script manually, but it fails to execute with cron.

Here's what `crontab -l` shows:

```
*/2 * * * *  /usr/bin/python2 home/pi/Documents/get_temperature.py
```

I guess there's something wrong with paths in the cron context but I
cannot manage to find what.

Answer (score 2):

The path to the `get_temperature.py` file you have given seems like an absolute path but has not started with a `/` (`/home`).

Unless you have `home/pi/Documents/get_temperature.py` in the home directory of the `crontab` owner, you need to correct the path:

```
*/2 * * * *  /usr/bin/python2 /home/pi/Documents/get_temperature.py
```

Comment: Thanks , it's working now. I have to buy some glasses I guess. 2 hours on that for a single / ! :-)

Comment: @SadE Please select it as accepted by clicking the tick mark on the left of my answer so that this this issue can be marked as solved..